# Splitting SHOUTcast track info into "Song title" and "Artist name"

Tags: jquery, ajax, shoutcast, internet-radio

I'm using this ['Now playing' jQuery plugin](https://github.com/Wavestreaming/jquery-shoutcast) and was wondering if there's a way to **split track info fetched from SHOUTcast** **(Artist name - Track title)** into two different strings: 'Artist name' and 'Track title' separately.

This is the basic configuration of the plugin:

```
$.SHOUTcast({
   host : '91.109.241.252',
   port : 8170,
   interval : 5000,
   stats : function(){
     $('#songtitle').text(this.get('songtitle','Temporarily Off Air'));
   }
}).startStats();
```

The code above will return, every 5 seconds, the name in the format **Artist name - Track title**.

Is there a way to adapt the current configuration in order to achieve the same with the string splitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the string "artist - song" and make a split:

```
var fullTitle = this.get('songtitle','Off Air').split(" - ");
```

Then get each item separately:

```
var artist = fullTitle[0];
var title = fullTitle[1];
```

And write it in different html tags:

```
$('#title').text(title);
$('#artist').text(artist);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, SHOUTcast style metadata includes one field.  To get the artist and track, the standard formatting is with a hyphen between the artist and track, as you have noticed.

```
const artist = meta.substr(0, meta.indexOf(' - '));
const title = meta.substr(meta.indexOf(' - ') + 3);
```

This will split up until the first `-`, giving you an Artist and Title (in theory), assuming there is no `-` in the artist name.  It will allow hyphens in the Title, because we're only splitting up to the first one.

Note that this will break if this isn't the format in use.  You might want to test the string first to see if there are even any hyphens.  It's common for DJ shows not to use this format.

Comment: I can't figure it out how to implement these two lines with the default configuration. Are they supposed to work inside the same function or in a separate one? Sorry, but my knowledge is very basic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another possible answer, that doesn't seem to have already been covered is to rewrite the artist/track separator, use a regular expression to find it in the artist - track combination and then put it back to it's original after storing the $matches from the regular expression. This is how we do it with our Artwork API, we use it to look up images for artist/title combinations and we have found this to be about the most reliable way to do it in PHP.

```
preg_match('/^(.*)%space%hyphen%space(.*)$/mi', $artist.'%space%hyphen%space'.$track, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$matches[0][0] = str_replace('%space%hyphen%space', ' - ', $matches[0][0]);
```

This is a particular problem with streams where a hyphen might have been used in the artist or title which will break the regular expression which is trying to find the separator.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd add a bit more information about one way to get artist/title data from a Shoutcast stream as the user who asked the original question still seems to be not sure about it.
The $songArray array contains all of the available information from the stream but in this case we are just interested in the artist and title.

```
     $splitSongRegex = "/\ \-\ /";    
     $streamUrl = "http://".$server.":".$port."/stats?sid=1"; //    Convert stream 
//  Convert stream XML data to lowercase Json array
    $xml = simplexml_load_string(strtolower($streamData), "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $streamDataArray = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    $song = ucwords(trim($streamDataArray['songtitle']));
    $songArray = preg_split($splitSongRegex, $song, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $artist = ucwords(trim($songArray[0]));
    $track = ucwords(trim($songArray[1]));
```

We use this to get artist/title information from our streams so it is tried and tested.